# storing large data in android

Tags: android, sqlite

I am pulling a large amount of json from a restful server. I use the GSON library from google to traverse this json and it works great. Now I want to save all of the json objects in my sqlite db, however I want to make use of a transaction to add all of them at once. This is difficult if you dont have all the objects ready in one datastructe. Since I am traversing the json one object at a time, I guess I would have to store that in a data structure such as an arraylist or hashmap and then afterwards use a database transaction to do the inserts fast. However... Storing a large amount of data aka 200 000 json objects into a structure in memory can take up a lot of memory and wil probably run out as well. What would be the best way to get all of that json objects into my sqlite db and at the same time not use up a lot of menory in otherwords storing and inserting in a way that allows for a lot of recycling.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know this is not the best implementation of handling large json input in Android, but it certainly works great.

So my solution is pretty simple:

While parsing the JSON code, make use of **prepared statements** and a db transaction to execute the inserts.
So in short, as soon as a JSON object is parsed, take that info, insert it into the db using the **prepared statement and the db transaction**, then move on to the next object.

I have just pulled 210 000 rows with 23 fields each (thats 4.6 million values) from a remote server via JSON and GSON and at the same time inserting all those values into my SQLite3 db on the device, in less than 5 minutes and without wasting any memory. Each iteration of parsing/inserting uses the same amount of memory and is cleaned on the next iteration.

So yeah, there's the solution. Obviously, this is not the best solution for commercial applications or tables with 1000 000 + records, but it works great for my situation.

Comment: You should accept your own answer if it's the best one. This way, futur readers will find the solution easily.

Comment: I will in 20 hours. @mithrop

Answer (score 1):

If you want to add a large amount of data at an unique moment : it will take a lot of memory anyway. 200 000 large JSON objects take a certain amount of memory and you will **not** be able to change it.

You can keep this behavior, but I think it's not a great solution because you create a huge memory consumption on both Android device and server. It will be better if you receive data part by part and adding them this way : but you need to have control on the server code.

If you are **absolutely** forced to keep this behavior, maybe you should receive all the data at the same time, parse them on a huge JSON object, then make multiple transactions. Check if every transaction was executed correctly and put back your database in a good state if not. It's a really bad way to do it, IMHO... but I don't know all your constraints.

To finish : avoid receiving a large amount of data at only one time. It will be better to make multiple requests to get partial data set. It will make your app less network dependant : if you loose the network for 2 seconds, maybe only one request will fail. So you will have to retry only one request and received again a small part of data. With only one huge request : if you loose the network, you will have to retry the entire request...

Comment: Thx for the advice. I agree that doing it this way is not ideal but I have little control over some aspects of the project. Will look into multiple chunks of data instead of one large request. Doing it with gson however does not create any large memory transactions where as doing one db insert at a time also is fine because it recycles memory, however it takes long. I want to see if I can keep the db open while doing transactions.

Answer (score 0):

Have you ever tried to add a lot of data (and I really mean a lot, in my case 2600 rows of data) into the Android-internal database (SQLite)?

If so, you propably went the same road as I did.

I tried a normal InsertStatement which was way to slow (10 sec. in my emulator). Then I tried PreparedStatements. The time was better but still unacceptable. (6 sec.). After some frustrating hours of writing code and then throwing it away, I finally found a good solution.

The Android-OS provide the InsertHelper as a fast way to do bulk inserts.

To give you an overview of the performance (measured with an emulator on a crap computer, trying to insert 2600 rows of data):

```
Insert-Statement
10 seconds
Prepared-Statements
6 seconds
InsertHelper
320 ms
```

You can speed up the insertion even more with temporarily disable thread locks. This will gain about 30 % more performance. However it’s important to be sure that only one thread per time is using the database while inserting data due to it’s not threadsafe anymore.

```
public void fillDatabase(HashMap<String, int[]> localData){
       //The InsertHelper needs to have the db instance + the name of the table where you want to add the data
       InsertHelper ih = new InsertHelper(this.db, TABLE_NAME);
       Iterator<Entry<String, int[]>> it = localData.entrySet().iterator();
       final int firstExampleColumn = ih.getColumnIndex("firstExampleColumn");
       final int secondExampleColumn = ih.getColumnIndex("secondExampleColumn");
       final int thirdExampleColumn = ih.getColumnIndex("thirdExampleColumn");
       try{
       this.db.setLockingEnabled(false);
               while(it.hasNext()){
                       Entry<String, int[]> entry = it.next();
                       int[] values = entry.getValue();
                       ih.prepareForInsert();
                       ih.bind(firstExampleColumn, entry.getKey());
                       ih.bind(secondExampleColumn, values[0]);
                       ih.bind(thirdExampleColumn, values[1]);
                       ih.execute();
               }
       }catch(Exception e){e.printStackTrace();}
               finally{
                       if(ih!=null)
                               ih.close();
                       this.db.setLockingEnabled(true);
               }
       }
```